# React Render HTML Code (dangerouslySetInnerHTML?)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building an App where Serverinput is being rendered.

Now I am trying to figure out, how it´s possible to display pure HTML. Because now it is only displayed as ...., where it should show an Image.

The question is, where should one call dangerouslySetInnerHTML() here to display all HTML as requested?

The Strings are being stores in an Array(messageList) that is being mapped. Userinput is escaped, so theres no problem on that side.

```
  let listItems = messageList.map(d => (
   <div >
     <p className={d.senderId + "timestamp"}>{d.time}</p>
     <p className={d.senderId} key={d.idCount} ref={d.idCount}>
       {" "}
        {d.text}{" "}
    </p>
   </div>
 ));

  let gif1 = <img className="gif" alt="" src={gif} />;

  return (
    <div >
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={__html: {listItems}} />
      <ul>{listItems}</ul>

    </div>
  );
```

Thanks a lot for any help that is given.

I updated the dangerousHTML where I thought it would work. But now it throws  - Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected }

Comment: `dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: {listItems}}}` it is ugly because it's dangerous and should be used with great care https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Comment: I don't think you need `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, just `{listItems}` is fine.

Answer (score 1):

You shuould have something like this for each element that you want to show the dynamic content

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={__html: {yourHtmlContent}} />
```

Comment: But where? Why is this needed? I'm not clear with OP code why he need to use.

Comment: Interesting but then it throws - "Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected }"

Comment: I need it in order to display a table or just a <br> that is being sent from the server

Comment: @DerekHaynes Update your question with your tried out code.

Comment: @DerekHaynes {listItems} is not your html. What is the path of the property with the dynamic html content from the server?

Comment: @HarimTejada as far as I understand OP doesn't need to use dangerouslySetInnerHTML. OP is just trying to render the items using map.

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar now I see the question updated and must agree with you

Comment: @HarimTejada I was already guessing that before your answer, BTW. That's why I've commented `Why is this needed?` - my first comment.

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar at first the question was asking how to render a html content that is gonna be sent from the server.

Comment: It's because OP is still not clear what's he doing. :)

Answer (score 1):

How I understood is that `Array(messageList)` contains a list of markup strings.

So you just need to join them.

```
const messageList = [
  "<h2>Header</h2>",
  "<body>This is body!</body>",
  "<footer>Footer!</footer>"
];

function createMarkup() {
  return { __html: messageList.join("") };
}

function MyComponent() {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup()} />;
}
```

It'd display something like this
[image]

You need to pass a string not an object as you do here.
(*as it's just [an implementation of innerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)*)

```
{__html: {listItems}}
```

Full source for completeness.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import "./styles.css";

const messageList = [
  "<h2>Header</h2>",
  "<body>This is body!</body>",
  "<footer>Footer!</footer>"
];

function createMarkup() {
  return { __html: messageList.join("") };
}

function MyComponent() {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup()} />;
}

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: "React"
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <MyComponent />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Working demo.
[image: Edit soanswer52225099]